# artificial neural networks, weights, lower and upper bounds

Tags: neural-network

Currently, I am implementing artificial neural networks by myself.

I have done to implement multi-layer perceptron and some experiments.

And I noticed that some weights exceed bounds between [-1, 1].

Should I limit this weight between [-1, 1]?

Thank you very much in advance.

:)

Comment: I think you shouldn't limit those at all. Sky is the limit!

Comment: Thank you for your comment @bc004346